# Facebook Connect Logging In Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I am using Facebook Connect with my app. Everything is set up, all the code WAS working. Around yesterday, I could login with my app, then post stuff and other functions. I don't recall making any real changes. Now, as usual, whenever I press login and it goes to a Safari page where I have to confirm that I want to use this app and it says who I am logging in as. If I press ok it goes back to the app. During this whole process, in the app, Facebook never logs in. REMEMBER: JUST YESTERDAY THIS WORKS, I DONT RECALL MAKING ANY CHANGES! Here is how the connection starts:

```
-(IBAction)connectToFacebook {

     [loginButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginWithFacebookPressed@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"387500177929927" andDelegate:self];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
 facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
  facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
  if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
   NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"user_likes", 
                    @"read_stream",
                    nil];
  [facebook authorize:permissions];
   [permissions release];
    }

   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self   selector:@selector(makeVisibleButtons) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
      }
```

So I press a button to call this IBAction. The NSTimer is not related, its just for the appearance of some buttons. Now, these two methods never get called (when I log it):

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
NSLog(@"handleOpenURL");

   }

- (void)fbDidLogin {

  NSLog(@"log in");
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
  [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
   [defaults synchronize];

    }
```

I don't understand why. Especially if it was working before. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: delete your app in simulator and run the project and check console in "NSLog(@"handleOpenURL");  NSLog(@"log in");" is working or not that methods.

Comment: @R.A yep not working... please go back to chat

Comment: Why did You delete your question? and re edited like this, such a waste comment????

Comment: because I re-asked it, that person gave me a correct answer. Sorry . @R.A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook API having `SSO(Single Sign On)`. So It will ask the user to login for only one time. This login is valid till that login tokens are expired. Check your code itself that you are storing your `token` and `expiration time` in `NSUserDefaults`. This will help the API to login again. If you want to make sure your app login functionality is working or not, then delete your app from simulator and again run it. It will ask your login credentials for the first time only. Hope you undertand.

Comment: hmmm.. im not fully understanding. I have followed exact steps on the official tutorial... anyways... in my code, the NSUserDefaults doesn't seem like its adding the token and expiration time. can you check? Im really sorry as I'm new to fb connect itself

Comment: @user1260708 Do you have idea about SSO? SSO means one time login.It is implemented in facebook API.So it will ask the user to login for the first time only (Not everytime user clicks login button).

Comment: oh ok, but wait.... why isn't my code working... i still don't really understand... @R.A

Comment: @user1260708 Hey your code is working 100% fine. when NSUserDefaults having values those methods will not get call. So there is nothing wrong.Put NSLog in that methods(which is not running) Just delete your project in simulator and run once again. For the first time only it will print in log.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I am not understanding what you want me to do. Where do you want me to log? If my code is working 100 percent, why is it not logging in like it used to

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8865/discussion-between-r-a-and-user1260708)

Comment: I reseted the iOS simulator and logged in for first time because i had to type in username and password and there still was no log.... and plus when I press the postToFacebook IBAction button, in the method I put an if statement saying if [facebook isSessionValid] then logged it and it doesn't log. Facebook returns isSessionValid as no!!!!!!